# increment a variable date by a month

Tags: shell-script, date, ksh

Is there way on how to increment an input date by one month without using the `date -d` option? My machine do not have that functionality.

Sample:

```
$yearmonth=201912
```

Expected Output:

```
201912
202001
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSIXly (assuming `$yearmonth` doesn't have leading zeros):

```
case $((yearmonth += 1)) in
  (*13) yearmonth=$((yearmonth + 100 - 12))
esac
```

With ksh/bash/zsh, you could shorten it to:

```
((++yearmonth % 100 <= 12)) || ((yearmonth += 100 - 12))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
(( yearmonth += ((yearmonth % 100) == 12)?(100 - 11):1 ))
```